# How to activate the virtualenv using shel lscript by crontab/cronjob

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron, virtualenv

I am working on the project where I need to run my script daily at a specific time. I am using crontab/cronjob to run shell script. Using shell script I want to activate virtualenv and python interpreter to run some commands and deactivate it. I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
bash
source virtual_env/bin/activate
cd src
python script.py
```

but didn't work for me

Note: I can activate my virtualenv and use `/home/bin/virtual_env/python` the interpreter manually but i wanted to it via shell script.

Comment: what's the error you get?
Try adding the full path to the 3rd line. Like-> `source /home/bin/virtual_env/bin/activate`
Also, don't think you need the second line `bash`

Comment: when i run  source virtual_env/bin/activate manually shell transfer to the (virtual_env)user@localhost:src$ then i check which python it;s picking up virtual_env python but using shell script when i check which python it's picking up machine python not virtual_env/bin/python

Comment: I need to run some set of commands on virtual_env python interpreter how to do that??

Comment: you should use python from the virtualenv, like-> `/home/bin/virtual_env/bin/python`

Comment: yes I am able to use python interpreter by putting command " /home/bin/virtual_env/bin/python " but i wanted to do same thing using shell script

Comment: you put that line on the shell script....

Answer (score 1):

Often there is no need to activate a virtual environment:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

PYTHON_BIN='/path/to/virtual_environment/bin/python'

pushd 'src'

"${PYTHON_BIN}" 'script.py'
```